# Segmentation fault when searching for the end of a string in main, but not in a function C++

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement a simple string length function. If I write everything in main, the code segfaults. However, if I declare a strlen function, then it does not. Why is this happening?

Why does the following code work

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int strlen(char *s)
{
    char *p = s;
    while (*p != '\0')
        p++;
    return p - s;
}


int main()
{
    char *s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << strlen(s) << endl;
}
```

While this code segfaults?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char *s;
    cin >> s;
    char *p = s;
    while (*p != '\0')
        p++;
    cout << p-s << endl;
}
```

Comment: Both programs exhibit UB as `s` is a dangling (unallocated) pointer in both cases. It just so happens that one example *appears* to work while the other crashes.

Comment: Also, be careful with names like `strlen`. There is `strlen` from `string.h` or `cstring`, `std::strlen` from `cstring`, any of which might get included by other std library headers. So better put your function inside a namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't allocated any memory for `s`. The reason it works in one case and not the other is likely because of the wonders of undefined behavior in C++.

Comment: strikethrough "likely"